# Some favicons returning "Unable to init from given binary data." when using Intervention Image

Tags: laravel, favicon, laravel-5.3, intervention

I am using intervention image to save favicons from a url.

I have this working, but only for some URL's. For example:

This doesn't work: http://www.speedhunters.com/favicon.ico

But this does: http://www.slamsanctuary.com/favicon.ico

My code is (The providerIcon is from scraping the page content):

```
\Image::make($info->providerIcon)->save(public_path('/uploads/' . $faviconName));
```

The error returned is:

```
NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 96:
Unable to init from given binary data.

in Decoder.php line 96
at Decoder->initFromBinary('h( ###&&&'''222333555666999???AAAIIIJJJLLLNNNOOOaaaeeeooopppssszzz{{{���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������7FHHD9(+HHHHHHHH@&FHHHHHHHHHH*#HHHH%)EHHF$GGGB /HHH-;HHH6.<FHHHH23HHHHHHHG0HHHHHHH?"    AHHHH>/! AHHH,3HHH+CHHHEHHG:1=HHHG$FHHHHHHHH85EHHHHG4!'' ') in AbstractDecoder.php line 65
```

Any ideas why one works and one doesn't?

Comment: I checked the favicons [here](http://www.checkfiletype.com/). The one on speedhunters is in a real icon format while the slamsanctuary one is a jpeg. What driver are you using? Icons are only [supported](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/formats) when using the Imagick driver,

Comment: @Doom5 Thanks, looking at what other people do I can see that they instead just store the favicon URL and show that in a img tag instead of saving the img.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something with `$faviconName`. Look at `<input type="file" name="faviconName">`